# Any audio player with segment repeat?

Tags: software-recommendation, music-player

I'm trying to learn to play some music by ears, but I'm not very good musician and I need to listen to some parts of composition hundreds of times before I correctly can play it. Can you guys suggest any light audio player which can repeatedly play given segments of file? If playback could be slowed down without tone pitch, that would be completely awesome.

Edit: my lookup directly concerns software for musicians, and I'm in need of more handful tool than what have been proposed in "possible duplicate" post.

Comment: To your edit: I'm sorry. Look at Takkat's solution below.

Answer (score 3):

### [Playitslowly](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playitslowly) [image: Install playitslowly]

This software is not only good for transcription but was originally designed for musicians to help learning how to play a given track. It comes with the following features:

> - Uses gstreamer for playback (mp3, ogg vorbis, midi, flv, etc. after codecs were installed)
> - Can also be used with ALSA and JACK
> - Change playback speed and/or pitch
> - Loop over parts of a track
> - Export to wav if needed
>
> Source: [Developer's Blog](http://29a.ch/playitslowly/)

[image]

Comment: Omg, that's awesome!